# New Line character in title attribute does not work in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form where I need to add new line character in to the title attribute of the anchor tag. I found a few solutions online but none of them work in my code.

I tried adding
`\n`
`&#013;`
`&#010;`
`&#013;&#010;`
`&lt;br&gt;`
`&#xA;`

not sure what is missing. Is it because of data-toggle that is blocking from breaking the title attribute?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').attr('novalidate', true);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 


<a class="helptext fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Additional information -&#013; You can provide further information here to for your&#013; application to issue a new card.&#013; Ensure a maximum of 200 characters&#013; is entered – including spaces."></a>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using bootstrap? If so, a popover may be a better solution.

Comment: I get what you are saying.. On removing the $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  I can add the line break in title attribute. A simple tool tip comes up instead of a fancy one but it still works. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the title with JavaScript works for me.

```
document.getElementById('asdf').title = 'line1\nline2';
```

Comment: Technically, since HTML line-breaks are CR+LF, this should be `'line1\r\nline2'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A popover would be a better solution, but it is possible to achieve this functionality in browser:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('form').attr('novalidate', true);
 //$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
 
 $('.helptext')[0].title = "I like\nlines"
        // you can also use $('.helptext').attr("title",decodeURI("I like%0A to%0Ause%0Alines"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="helptext fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" title="Additional information -&#013; You can provide further information here to for your&#013; application to issue a new card.&#013; Ensure a maximum of 200 characters&#013; is entered – including spaces.">test</a>
```